# Angular and Datepair won't play nice

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, datepicker, timepicker

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now and I think it's time to turn to you fine folks. Ok I'm building a calendar app that's using Angular + datepair/datepicker/timepicker. I have a start time field and an end time field. It would be nice if a user cannot pick choose an end time that occurs before the start time. On the [Timepicker website](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/) the very last example is exactly what I'm trying to do but I can't seem to get it to work with Angular.

Here's the example that was on timepicker's site:

```
<p id="datepairExample">
    <input type="text" class="date start" />
    <input type="text" class="time start" /> to
    <input type="text" class="time end" />
    <input type="text" class="date end" />
</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datepair.js"></script>
<script>
    // initialize input widgets first
    $('#datepairExample .time').timepicker({
        'showDuration': true,
        'timeFormat': 'g:ia'
    });

    $('#datepairExample .date').datepicker({
        'format': 'yyyy-m-d',
        'autoclose': true
    });

    // initialize datepair
    $('#datepairExample').datepair();
</script>
```

Here's my code.

Angular directives:

```
viasam.directive('datepicker', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, $element) {
      $element.datepicker({
        format: 'd/m/yyyy',
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
      });
    }
  }
});

viasam.directive('timepicker', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, $element) {
      $element.timepicker({
        'minTime': '8:00am',
        'maxTime': '8:00pm',
        'timeFormat': 'g:i A',
        'showDuration': true,
        'scrollDefaultNow': true
      });
    }
  }
});

viasam.directive('datepair', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, $element) {
      $element.datepair({
        'defaultDateDelta': 0,
        'defaultTimeDelta': 7200000
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The form:

```
<div id="datepair">

  <%= form_tag blocks_create_es_path, :class => "form-horizontal" do %>

    <div datepair>

      <%= text_field_tag(:start_day, nil, class: 'date start datepicker form-control input-sm', :datepicker => 'datepicker') %>


      <%= text_field_tag(:start_hour_and_minute, nil, class: 'start form-control input-sm', :timepicker => 'timepicker') %>

      <%= text_field_tag(:end_hour_and_minute, nil, class: 'end form-control input-sm', :timepicker => 'timepicker') %>

      <%= text_field_tag(:end_day, nil, class: 'date end datepicker form-control input-sm', :datepicker => 'datepicker') %>

      <%= submit_tag "Abrir bloque de tiempo" %>

    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you put the directive on a div containing many fields? they'll disappear

Comment: I updated my answer. I was trying to reproduce the example provided by timepicker's documentation but I think it's not going to work the same way in this case since I'm trying to use Angular as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did. This is my timepicker directive:

```
.directive('timePicker', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.on('change', function () {
                if (element.hasClass('start')) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        var $el = element.closest('[date-pair]').find('input.end'),
                            endScope = angular.element($el).isolateScope();

                        endScope.$apply(function () {
                            endScope.ngModel = $el.val();
                        });
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
            element.timepicker({
                timeFormat: 'H:i',
                forceRoundTime: true
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And my datePair directive is pretty similar to yours:

```
.directive('datePair', [function () {
    restrict: 'AC',
    link: function (scope, element) {
        element.datepair();
    }
}]);
```

Your HTML could look something like this:

```
<div date-pair>
    <input time-picker class="time start" ng-model="something.start">
    <input time-picker class="time end" ng-model="something.end">
</div>
```

You could still use your date-pair directive, but do note that I added a hyphen in my attribute.

What happens is that when the `change` event is triggered in a start timePicker, it'll update the scope for the end timePicker to reflect the change made by the jQuery plugin.

It's not too fast though, it usually updates within a second (less than a second most of the time)